# pymysql can't connect to db from venv

Tags: mysql, virtualenv, python-3.6

I have installed and populated a mysql db on Ubuntu and have tested to be sure I can access it via pymysql. I am now trying to access it through pymysql via a script running in a virtual environment. Mysql is refusing the connection:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

The same commands work fine when I'm not in the venv.  Do I need to provide a different grant to myself to access via the venv, or what?

Comment: What is your `pymysql` connection construct? Are you specifying [unix_socket](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html)? Where is your mysql listening on its socket? If you `strace -fe trace=network,connect {pythonscript}` where it it trying to connect to?

Comment: Turns out the daemon had gotten stopped. I was thrown off by the "connection refused." I assumed it couldn't "refuse" if it wasn't running.

Comment: Agree, its one of those network stack error messages that should of been better 40 years ago, but we're stuck with it for the foreseeable future.